# MS Access Linked Tables to MYSQL via ODBC refreshes on some machines but not all

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Here's the deal..  I have a MS Access DB with a number of linked tables to a MYSQL DB.  I was having issues running queries on my c# program only to find out the machine I was coding from is clearly not reading the DB properly.

So to make things simple I open the Access DB with Access and tried to open a table where I knew what the data should be.  The machine I'm coding from does not get the latest data from the MySQL DB.

I open the SAME Access DB from two other machines on my network that I know my c# program works correctly.  From there the Access DB shows all the updated data from MySQL.

Unfortunately I've come into this project in the middle.  I'm only just learning about linked tables.  I see there's tons of info about it and how to do it programatically but I just don't understand how it works fine on two machines.. but the other machines see some data, just not the latest.  It has nothing to do with my c# program since I see the issue with I'm reading the DB via access.

Is there something...  some code or something installed on the two working machines that allows it to keep up to date that I'm missing?  If there is.. I just simply don't know where to look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your MySQL drivers are up to date on that machine.   Also are you using DSNs to access the Access database?  If so that machines DSN may be pointing to an out of date development Access database.